# How authentication tag is calculated in AES-GCM-256

Tags: java, encryption, aes-gcm

I have a sample code,which encrypt and decrypt a string using AES-GCM-256.

I am unable to understand,how authentication tag is being generated on encrypter side and how is that being used on decrypter side.

Actually here i am not generating authentication tag either on encrypter side nor validating decrypter side,so is it being done internally by library itself.

```
private static String encrypt(String s, byte[] k) throws Exception {
        SecureRandom r = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        // Generate 128 bit IV for Encryption
        byte[] iv = new byte[12]; r.nextBytes(iv);

        SecretKeySpec eks = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        // Generated Authentication Tag should be 128 bits
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, eks, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
        byte[] es = c.doFinal(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // Construct Output as "IV + CIPHERTEXT"
        byte[] os = new byte[12 + es.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, os, 0, 12);
        System.arraycopy(es, 0, os, 12, es.length);

        // Return a Base64 Encoded String
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os);

    }

    private static String decrypt(String eos, byte[] k) throws Exception {
        // Recover our Byte Array by Base64 Decoding
        byte[] os = Base64.getDecoder().decode(eos);

        // Check Minimum Length (IV (12) + TAG (16))
        if (os.length > 28) {
            byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(os, 0, 12);
            byte[] es = Arrays.copyOfRange(os, 12, os.length);

            // Perform Decryption
            SecretKeySpec dks = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, dks, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));

            // Return our Decrypted String
            return new String(c.doFinal(es), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Do you want to understand how GHASH works?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Actually i want to know, the generation logic of authentication tag,is it related to AAD,how position of authentication tag is always fixed ,at the last of ciphertext.

Comment: a) *"the generation logic of authentication tag"* That would be a little complicated to show here. Just look into the GCM specification and if you have a specific question about the process, just ask on [crypto.se]. b) *"is it related to AAD"* Yes, the associated data is also authenticated by the authentication tag. c) *"how position of authentication tag is always fixed ,at the last of ciphertext"* You'd need to read the whole plaintext in order to make some kind of authentication tag. Since the JCE API doesn't permit to return some additional data, it must be returned in a different manner.